# Confused by python descriptors and __get__()

Tags: python, descriptor

This a simple class, i just want to test the feature about `__get__()`
The code is :

```
class Des(object):
    def __init__(self,num):
        self.num = num
    def __get__(self, obj, typ = None):
        return self.num

class A(object):
    des = Des(1)
    print 'the des in class is ',des

a = A()
print  'the des in object is ',a.des
print a.__dict__
print A.__dict__
```

the output is :

```
the des in class is  <Des object at 0x7f5fb550ded0>
the des in object is  1
{}
{'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__module__': '__builtin__', 'des': <Des object at 0x7f5fb550ded0>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None}
```

my question is why the why the outputs of `des` are `des` is different (one is 1 `type(int)`, one is object `type(Des)`). And the output of `a.__dict__` and `A.__dict` is also different. What's the fucntion of `__get__()`, and how to use it.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `__get__` has anything to do with attributes and `__dict__`? It is part of the *descriptor protocol*; binding methods and properties.

Comment: How much do you already understand of descriptors? Does my [answer on  `property` objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work/17330273#17330273) help here at all?

Comment: and perhaps [Descriptors and direct access: Python reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19409373) is relevant here too.

Comment: try `a = A()` to `a = A` -- > then it gives same answer.Its happen because you try to allocate class a method but in `class A` no any other method so if you want same answer then at allocation time remove `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the outputs of des are different (one is 1 type(int), one is object type(Des)).

In the first case, you are print the instance of `Des` in the `A` class statement's body. At this point it's nothing else than an ordinary Python object - no descriptor protocol involved since you are not doing an attribute access on a class or instance, since the `A` class doesn't even exist yet - so you get the default representation of the `Des` object.

In the second case, you are looking up (attribute access) the name `des` on an instance of `A`. The attribute resolution mechanism (implemented in `object.__getattribute__`) finds the name `des` in `A.__dict__` and finds out the associated object implements `__get__`, so it calls `A.__dict__["des"].__get__(a, A)` and returns the result - in this case A.**dict**["des"].num`, which is`int(1)`.

> And the output of `a.__dict__` and `A.__dict__` is also different.

Yes of course. `A.__dict__` is the dict of class `A`, `a.__dict__` is the dict of instance `a`. Why would you expect same to share the same dict ?

> What's the function of `__get__()`, and how to use it.

Martijn Pieters's links will answer this question.

Comment: thanks your answer , it help me a lot, and sovled most of my Confusion.

Comment: thanks your answer , it help me a lot, and it solved most of my Confusion.But I still have some question. first how do the python interpreter know to call A.__dict__["des"].__get__(a, A). I think it will check if the  associated object(Des)  has implements the __get__ methond. Rigth??

Comment: @ArthurGeorge you know you can edit your question don't you ? And yes, _as I already mentionned in my answer_, `object.__getattribute__()` (not "the python interpreter") will check if there's a _class_ attribute implementing `__get__ `,  as documented here https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors

Answer (score 0):

in your code the  `des` is a class attribute and in a descriptor it(class attr) will call the `get()` ,in the next  `a.des` calls the  `call()` method so , thats the reason you got the different output (in your example output).